# Document is not defined on node.js - How can i import a variable from another .js file to node.js server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, jsdom

Edit: Actually, my problem is "How to use "value" from selection.js in the server.js ? " I want to direct user to a searching page according to his/her choice .

i am new at web programming. I have server.js and  a selection.js. 
server.js is a node file, and my server is in it. selection.js is my item class changer. I am changing selected item's class with selection.js and i am trying to use this selected item from server.js. When i try below codes, i am taking this shit: Document is not defined on node.js

It is really painful. I am trying to solve it about hours. But, nothing! 
Pls, help me :/

selection.js :

```js
var iconContainer = document.getElementById('iconContainer');
var icon = iconContainer.getElementsByClassName("item");

for (var i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) {
  icon[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
    
  const btnSearch = document.querySelector("#btnSearch");
  btnSearch.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // get the active item's value
    const value = document.querySelector(".item.active span").innerText;
    console.log("value: ", value);
    // do fetch
    

  });
  
});
}
module.exports={searchPath: "/"+value};
```

server.js:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var path = require('path');
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// '/' girdisi için index.html getirilecek.
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
      });
    
});
//---------------------------------------------------
// Server kuruyoruz.
var server = app.listen(8081,"127.0.0.1", function () {
   var host = server.address().address;
   var port = server.address().port;
   
   console.log('Server http://' + host + ':' + port+' adresinde çalışıyor...');
});

var search = require('./public/js/selection');
console.log(search.searchPath);
```

Comment: Please do a little reading about how http is a client/server protocol and how your server code runs on the server and the rendered HTML page lives and runs in the browser, not on your server.  So, any DOM manipulations (referencing the `document` object) would need to be done in Javascript that lives inside your web page and runs in the browser, not in your server.  The browser can communicate with your server via Ajax calls (http requests) or webSocket connections if the web page needs to ask the server for some data or needs to send the server some data.

Comment: If you want more specific suggestions on how to solve your problem, then please describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, not an error you ran into using your solution. Then and only then, would we have a chance at describing a goo way to solve your original problem. What you have written so far is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you've described a problem with your attempted solution and NOT described the actual higher level problem. That keeps us from being able to suggest better approaches to the actual problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your reply, i will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

So, the code you label as `selection.js` needs to be in your web page, either directly embedded or linked from a `<script>` tag so it can run in the web page in the browser.

Then, that code can make an Ajax call using the XMLHttpRequest or `fetch()` interfaces in the browser to a route on your server and pass the desired value.

That route on your server (which you need to define and add code for) can then examine that value and decide what data to return the the Ajax call.

Your Javascript in the web page, then receives that returned data from the Ajax call and decides what to do with it such as insert new content in the page for the user to see, cause the browser to load a different page or refresh the current page or whatever else is appropriate.

Comment: Do i have to use Ajax ? I don't know anything about ajax, i don't want to be a web developer. I just finish this project, thats it.  It takes too long time for me if i should learn new things.

Comment: @quality38 - If your web page wants to get a value from the server, you have to to use Ajax or webSocket.  Those are the two ways to do it.  The `fetch()` interface is pretty easy to use for Ajax.